# Why won't this plugin (for minecraft java) work?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I use eclipse (keep in mind, I'm a beginner), I have made a bukkit plugin which doesn't work - when it is put into the plugins folder of my Minecraft server, it doesn't change anything, and the custom commands don't work. I have installed the correct version of bukkit. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Pastebin - https://pastebin.com/PbhLFic2`PbhLFic2`

```java
package customcommands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class customcommands extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("This plugin is now on and fuctioning");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("Hello, " + player.getName() + "!");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onCommand1(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("discord") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("§c§lDiscord §8§l- §e Want to connect with us? §e§dhttps://discord.gg/T9fhEDh");
        }
        return false;

    }

    public boolean onCommand2(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("website") && sender instanceof Player) {

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            player.sendMessage("§c§lShop §8§l- §e Want to visit the server website?  §e§dhttps://noname-mc.enjin.com/");

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant code in the question, not just link to another site where we'd have to download it.

Comment: You also need to elaborate on "doesn't work".

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - My Apologies, the proposals have been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: You can include multi-line code by putting it in triple back-ticks. Like so: ```int a = 0;```. If you also add "java" to the first triple of back-ticks, you also get syntax highlighting.

Comment: @MelvinWM could you please elaborate or show me a copy of what you mean? I'm not too sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Razzmatical Sorry, I meant in your question here on StackOverflow, you can get better formatting for your question. I have edited it for you, so it should show up nice and well-formatted now. If you edit your answer, you should be able to see the part with triple backticks and your code inside.

Comment: Reg. your question, I am not familiar with bukkit, but there are some general approaches you can try out. This approach should be useful for narrowing down the problem and making it easier for you to debug and figure out: Have you taken an existing example for bukkit, followed the instructions for setting it up, and gotten it working? If so, the part with using bukkit should work, so you may be able to look at the differences between that example and your code and possibly find the issue. If not, it may be an issue reg. using bukkit and not your code specifically.

Comment: @MelvinWM - What does java``` do? I've also looked online for a while and found no solutions, but thank you!

Comment: It turns a generic code-block into a code-block that that has syntax highlighting specific for Java. Different languages have different highlighting, and therefore, to enable StackOverflow to highlight the code snippet with the correct highlighting, you can write which language the code of the code-block is written in after the triple backticks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the snippet you have provided. I highly suggest you read through some tutorials, specifically for this problem, have a read of this [Spigot Wiki post](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-a-simple-command/); the process is the same for Bukkit and Spigot.

Your command won't work because you haven't registered a CommandExecutor, you would need to make the following changes to [`customcommands`](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html):

```
public class customcommands extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("This plugin is now on and functioning");
        this.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }
```

But you have multiple `onCommand` methods, CommandExecutors don't work like that, you'll need to make a new CommandExecutor for each new `/`command, for which you will need to place in other classes and register them.

You're also returning `false` which will prompt the CommandExecutor to return back to the player the default usage for the command, as supplied in your `plugin.yml`; if the command was successful, you should return `true`.

I would suggest that you try Java tutorials first before diving into the Bukkit API as you will struggle otherwise.